# Curve cover direction

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I have interesting problem:

Let's imagine a wire bent into a curve. We have a set of non-stretchable plastic covers of various diameters. The larger the diameter of the cover, the deeper it can be placed on the wire. The cover has some direction. With the casing diameter approaching zero, the direction is that of the derivative at the ends of the curve.

If the cover is wide enough so that the entire curve fits in it, there is only one cover instead of two (starting and ending) and its direction can be calculated using the "rotating calipers" algorithm (in practice, a poly-line can be used instead of a smooth curve).

How to calculate the direction depending on the curve (implemented as a polyline) and the width of the cover?

Problem goal: image reconstruction where we have many polylines and gaps between parts of polylines, we need to find the most appropriate line B for line A and connect them by filling the gap - if tail cover of A intersect with head cover of B, optionally, we also limit the cover lengths.

Hint: maybe easier parameter will be not width but rather depth; if depth small - direction will equals to direction first/last segment; up to the length of this segment; next, when will covered two segments, direction will between direction first and second segment, weighted with (first segment length, length of part of second segment); next will weighted direction between (first segment, second segment, part of third segment) etc. Using rotating calipers on k first/last of n vertex ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

First of all, it's worth recalling why I actually came up with this problem. It is intended to be used to test whether linestrings can be attached to the first group; the first one encountered sorted by length, with a minimum length of e.g. 50 pixels. These polylines actually have a small number of segments: 1, 2, maybe 3. They are created by dividing the polylines in such a way that between the first and last segment there must be less than 90 degrees (or maybe some smaller specified value), and they all have to turn in one direction: if 1 is 15 degrees relative to 0, then 2 relative to 1 can be 20 but not -20 degrees.

Let's start with 3 points - two segments.

```
std::vector<cv::Point2d> points = {{100, 100}, {300, 200}, {450, 50}};
```

Check whether they do not form a degenerate triangle:

```
double deg = degen(points);
if (deg<1) 
    replacing two segments with one
```

where

```
double degen(const vector<cv::Point2d> &tr) {
  double a = cv::norm(tr[1] - tr[0]);
  double b = cv::norm(tr[2] - tr[1]);
  double c = cv::norm(tr[0] - tr[2]);
  return min(min(a+b-c, b+c-a), c+a-b);
}
```

lambda can be from 0 to 1. Denotes the relative position of the endpoint on the second segment

```
//lambda: 0..1
double hForLambda(const vector<cv::Point2d> &tr, double lambda) {
  cv::Point2d p;
  p.x = (1-lambda)*tr[1].x + lambda*tr[2].x;
  p.y = (1-lambda)*tr[1].y + lambda*tr[2].y;
  //side lengths
  double a = cv::norm(tr[1] - tr[0]);
  double b = cv::norm(p - tr[1]);
  double c = cv::norm(tr[0] - p);
  //Heron formula
  double s = 0.5 * (a + b + c);
  double area = sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));
  double h = (2 * area) / c;
  return h;
}
```

h is computed from area, and area from side lengths by Heron formula.
We need the opposite: calculating lambda based on h. However, we do not need to use bisection, just interpolate with a quadratic polynomial, which approximates very well (less than 1 pixel difference for sides about 200 pixels) and use the school formula for a quadratic trinomial.

```
std::vector<cv::Point2d> interpolatePoints(3);
//interpolatePoints[0] = {0, hForLambda(points, 0)}; == 0
interpolatePoints[1] = {0.5, hForLambda(points, 0.5)};
interpolatePoints[2] = {1, hForLambda(points, 1)};
double A,B,C;
lagrangeInterpolationTrinomial(interpolatePoints, A, B, C);
```

where

```
void lagrangeInterpolationTrinomial(const std::vector<cv::Point2d>& points, double& A, double& B, double& C) {
  double x0 = points[0].x, x1 = points[1].x, x2 = points[2].x;
  double y0 = points[0].y, y1 = points[1].y, y2 = points[2].y;

  double dx0 = x1 - x0;
  double dx1 = x2 - x1;
  double dx2 = x0 - x2;

  double m01 = dx0 * dx1;
  double m12 = dx1 * dx2;
  double m02 = dx0 * dx2;

  A = -(y0 / m02 + y1 / m01 + y2 / m12);
  B = (y0 * (x1 + x2) / m02) + (y1 * (x0 + x2) / m01) + (y2 * (x0 + x1) / m12);
  C = -(x1*x2*y0/m02 + x0*x2*y1/m01 + x0*x1*y2/m12);
}
```

is given width
school formula:

```
double c = C - width;
double delta = B*B-4*A*c;
assert(delta>=0);
double x1 = (-B - sqrt(delta))/(2*A);
double x2 = (-B + sqrt(delta))/(2*A);
```

delta is >=0 because not degenerated
x1 is bad solution, x2 is correct

```
x2 = min(x2, 1);
```

And already we have point on second segment.
Now we compute bounding rotate box:

we have already h from  hForLambda
and previously computed longest side:

```
double c = cv::norm(tr[0] - p);
```

We have size of box:

```
cv::Size2f size(c, h);
```

and angle equals angle the same longest side:

```
double angle = atan2(tr[0].y - tr[2].y, tr[0].x - tr[2].x)*180/M_PI;
```

We must compute center of height, first computing intersection between height and side
fist compute line coefficients A,B,C form AxBy+C=0

```
double A, B, C;
lineCoefficients(tr[0], tr[2], A, B, C);
```

where

```
void lineCoefficients(const cv::Point& p1, const cv::Point& p2, double& A, double& B, double& C) {
  double deltaX = p2.x - p1.x;
  double deltaY = p2.y - p1.y;
  A = deltaY;
  B = -deltaX;
  C = -(A * p1.x + B * p1.y);
}
```

next A,B,C perpendicular line:

```
double Ah, Bh, Ch;
perpendicularLine(A, B, C, tr[1], Ah, Bh, Ch);
```

where

```
void perpendicularLine(const double A, const double B, const double C,
                       const cv::Point& point, double& hA, double& hB, double& hC) {
  hA = -B;
  hB = A;
  hC = -hA * point.x - hB * point.y;
}
```

next, find intersection with side

```
cv::Point2d hBase = findIntersection(A, B, C, Ah, Bh, Ch);
```

and center of height:

```
cv::Point2d hCenter;
hCenter.x = (tr[1].x + hBase.x)/2.0;
hCenter.y = (tr[1].y + hBase.y)/2.0;
```

but it is not box center
center must be parallel to the position of the center of the triangle

```
cv::Point2d trLineCenter;
trLineCenter.x = (tr[0].x + tr[2].x)/2;
trLineCenter.y = (tr[0].y + tr[2].y)/2;
cv::Point2d vec = trLineCenter - hBase;
cv::Point2d center = hCenter + vec;
```

and finally

```
return cv::RotatedRect(center, size, angle);
```

Is we have 3 segments:
instead

x2 = min(x2, 1), we go to third segment

Next we can extend the length of the first box in the group and check whether it intersects with any box of another polyline.

We can use rotatedRectangleIntersection – standard OpenCV method

Comment: The original question was too general for the actual needs expressed in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the rotating calipers algorithm, but if it's not computationally expensive, then an idea is to numerically find the subcurve with one end fixed as the same as the original curve such that the minimal cover over this subcurve has same width as the target cover. Since the width of the minimal cover of such subcurves monotonically increases with the length of the subcurve, one could try bisection search over the unknown endpoint of the subcurve, with the initial interval values being the two ends of the full curve, and evaluating the subcurves using the rotating calipers algorithm.

Repeating this but fixing the other end instead would then yield the two desired covers.